# iOS GMSAutoComplete result with in boundaries

Tags: ios, google-maps

I need to find out Google Places with in boundary. I have implemeted Google place autocomplete and tried to pass bounds for region. But it still gives me result that are not present in that boundaries.

```
 GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [self getGMSBoundsWithRadiusInMeters:20];

GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity;

GMSPlacesClient *placeClient=[GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];

[placeClient autocompleteQuery:place
                          bounds:bounds
                          filter:filter
                        callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                            if (error != nil) {
                                NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                return;
                            }

                            searchedPlaces=results;

                            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet
                                                                  alloc ]initWithTitle:@"Select Place" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

                            for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {

                                [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[self getPlaceTitle:result.attributedFullText.string]];
                            }
                          [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

                        }];

-(GMSCoordinateBounds*)getGMSBoundsWithRadiusInMeters:(float)radius{
CLLocationCoordinate2D center=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.77, 77.77);


MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, radius*2, radius*2);

CLLocationCoordinate2D  northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta/2, region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta/2);
CLLocationCoordinate2D  southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta/2, region.center.longitude + region.span.longitudeDelta/2);

GMSCoordinateBounds* bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]
                               initWithCoordinate: northEast
                               coordinate: southWest];

return bounds;
}
```

But it returns result that are beyond this radius. Can anyone suggest how to get result with in the boundaries.

Comment: Who sover gives downvote. Can you please tell me what is the reason for the same. Or do you know the answer then share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if iOS SDK provides any option for providing radius boundary in their Google Place SDK. But I have resolved it by implementing their web API for near by search at my PHP backend.

This helps me to filter out results based on my radius.

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

may you can fetch userLocation through CLLLocationManager and pass it to the GMSPlacesClient in this way

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_userLocation.latitude + 0.15, _userLocation.longitude + 0.15);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_userLocation.latitude - 0.15, _userLocation.longitude - 0.15);
    userBound = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast
                                                      coordinate:southWest];
```